# Get DOM element given its string index in the document's HTML

Tags: javascript, string, dom, element

I have my document's HTML source as a string and the index `i` at which an element begins in this string.

I would like a function `getElementByIndex(i)` that returns the JavaScript DOM object corresponding to the element beginning at position `i` in the page's HTML string.

For example, I would expect the following behavior:

```
> var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
> markup

    "<head></head><body><div id="a"></div><div id="b"></div></body>"

> getElementByIndex(19)        // 19 is the index of the first div's 
                               // '<' character in the markup string

     <div id="a"></div>

> getElementByIndex(19) === document.getElementById("a")

     true

> getElementByIndex(19) === document.getElementById("b")

     false
```

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting from `getElementByIndex` ? Could you relate with your markup ?

Comment: The string `<div id="a"></div>` begins at position 19 in the markup string. Does that clarify what `getElementByIndex` should do?

Comment: `index` of a `strng` ?

Comment: `markup.substring(19, 37)` returns `<div id="a"></div>`

Comment: What is not happening ?

Comment: I am looking for an implementation of `getElementByIndex`.

Comment: How do you know the `index` ?

Comment: I get it from somewhere else. (I have string HTML snippets saved in my database, and I use `wrapper.indexOf(html_snippet)` to obtain the index.)

Comment: It'd probably be easier to just parse the HTML snippet you have available and use whatever attributes it contains as selectors. If you know the string contains `id="a"` then just do `document.getElementById('a')`.

Comment: @dyagmin, But how will comparison work ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by comparison. Index `i` specifies the starting position of a specific element in the `wrapper` string. I want the DOM object for that element.

Comment: He wants to get the innerHTML of an element as a string.  His function would then identify the element which is indicated by the substring of the inner HTML that starts at a specified position in the innerHTML string.  I don't think that it is possible since I don't believe that the layout of the string is preserved when converting the string to the DOM model and then extract it as an innerHTML.  You can look for a child element of an element that has a specified id.  What do you want to do?

Comment: A user selects text on a page, and I'm using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki) to add a `<span>` around the selected text so that I can style the selection. I am not able to save the modified page in my database, so instead I just save the selected HTML. Later, when I redisplay the page, I have the HTML snippet the user previously selected, and I would like to obtain the corresponding DOM element(s) to pass into the `insertNode` [function](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range#insertnodenode-node) of a Rangy range, then use that range object to add the `<span>`s again.

Comment: If you have jquery available you could use `$(snippet)`. If `$(snippet).prop('id')` returns something, use that value for getElementById. If not, then use $(snippet).prop('class') or something else. If all else fails, use $(snippet).prop('tagName') and use `$($(snippet).prop('tagName')).each(...)` to loop through every element of the same tag and compare `$(snippet).html()` to `$(this).html()` to see if the inner html is the same.

Comment: It is not possible without a detailed parsing and node creation up to the specified index at least. So a robust solution is to parse the string at least to the specified position and simultaneously create the dom node corresponding to that substring. Then the element you seek will be the final node returned by this process

Answer (score 0):

```
function getElementByIndex(htmlString, tagName, index) {
  var numOfEleBefore = htmlString.substr(0, index).split('<' + tagName).length - 1;
  return element = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName.toUpperCase())[numOfEleBefore]
}
```

You can try this, but it makes several assumptions:

1. The html must be minified into a single string
2. You know the type of tag you are trying to find
3. The html **exactly** mimics the minified string mentioned in #1 in order, number of spaces in tags, and attributes assigned to each tag. Like a single space causes it to fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tag may not have an id. This is why I'm having so much difficulty implementing this function. If the tag had an id, I could simply use `document.getElementById` to get the desired object (as you did in your solution).

Comment: You may be able to get the element by using `getElementsByTagName` if you knew the how many of the same element there were before the desired element (you could count this by using `split` on a substring of the `html` string from the beginning to the given index).

Comment: The all property of an element object is a list of all of the child elements.

Comment: The all property of an element object is a list of all of the child elements.  (Look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp for the methods and properties of an element.)  You can then look for the child element having the properties you specify.  What do you want to do with this proposed function?  Then try to find another function specification that will satisfy the desired task.